# PHP Unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, simpletest

Is there any EASY php testing Framework and may be simpler than simpletest and not command line based like PHPUnit ?

Comment: I voted for Simpletest. See a live copy of it being used for Samstyle PHP Framework at: http://code.google.com/p/samstyle-php-framework

Comment: Just include one PHP file to use Enhance PHP. That's pretty simple... http://www.enhance-php.com/

Answer (score 16):

[Simpletest](http://www.simpletest.org/)

Actually [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#PHP) is a list of all the common PHP unit testing frameworks.

I think you will find that the testing frameworks themselves have little interest in developing fancy GUIs. There is however several third party tools/applications/plugins that you can checkout. I use the phpunit integration within Netbeans a lot, and it works very good.

Comment: commandline means running the testing from command line like `php /tests/run_tests.php`

Comment: well duh, but is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: i run phpunit mostly in netbeans which has some nice integration with code coverage etc.

Comment: Thanks that was the closest answer :)

Answer (score 13):

The requirement that it be

> not command line based

is curious.  In traditional PHP development you make an edit, load a webpage in your browser, and repeat.  Instead, you can make an edit, run a piece of your test suite at the command line, then repeat.  I have discovered the latter practice is usually much faster.

Comment: That's a very helpful downvote!

Comment: helped to revoke that downvote. however i would still prefer run test suites on browsers.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't figure out if it meant, "No, my traditional development isn't like that,"  or "Hey, browser based is much faster,"  or "Take that for no particular reason."

Comment: Ehm, me neither. Besides i never thought of web based when i thought of non-cli interface, i immediately thought of guis such as netbeans/eclipse. Why would one want to run the test suites in the browser window anyway? When you can have it inside your IDE. Well of course if you're not using an IDE that makes for some interesting dilemma. But otherwise?

Comment: The downvote was most likely because it doesn't answer his question.